# deleting previous message discord bot

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to making bot that'll send message on last line and delete it after someone send something then send a new one

example: 
someone1: hello 
bot: hi 
someone2: hello 
bot: deleting previous message and send new hi

here is my code (still incomplete because I don't know what to do)

```
  const lastmessage = client.user.lastMessage
  if (lastmessage) { 
    message.channel.send('hi').then(sentMessage => {
     sentMessage.delete({ timeout: 6000 })
  });
```

Comment: why do you want to delete the old message in the first place?

Comment: to prevent spam and I want to keep bot only sends message at last line

Comment: do you mean that you want to prevent the bot from responding to its self?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the member object of the client by using `client.me`, This will allow you to find the last message sent by the bot using the `lastMessage` property.

Getting the bot's last message

```
const { lastMessage } = client.me;
```

For deleting it once someone else says hello. Make sure you delete the last message before sending the new one, otherwise the newly sent message will be instantly deleted.

Also. The `timeout` option on `Message#delete` will soon be deprecated. Use a `setTimeout()` function instead.

```
lastMessage.delete();
message.channel.send('hi');
```